# How to create DMG file which will allow autostarting an application efter bootup

Tags: macos, dmg

I want to create a DMG file for my application. That DMG file must give me the following functionlity.

1-- If I reboot my computer then my application must start automatically.

How to achieve this type of functionality in my DMG file.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: A DMG file is a disk image, it just contains files. It doesn't control what happens when your computer boots or launch applications. Why don't you just copy the application to your hard drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please have a look on the below link.
The linke given below denotes how to make an autostart application

[How can I write a startup script for Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857838/how-can-i-write-a-startup-script-for-mac-os-x)

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, a dmg's purpose is not for booting. Drag and drop or otherwise add the application to your Preference Panes/Accounts/Login items